# R: how to use paste() function in r for the list arg?

Tags: r, list, paste, quote

I am confused about the `paste()` function in R.

This is my r code:

```
paste(cols=list("speed###","dist"), rows=list("speed"))
```

The ideal output should be:

```
cols=list("speed###","dist"), rows=list("speed")
```

But the actual output was:

```
"speed### speed" "dist speed"
```

Can anyone help me to figure out and get the ideal output?

I will appreciate any reply here!

Thank you!

Best regards!

Comment: I guess you need `c` instead of `paste`.  Do you need `c(cols=list("speed###","dist"), rows=list("speed"))`

Comment: Or `list` instead of `paste`. The 'ideal output' should be stated in terms of an actual R object.

Comment: Hi, @akrun. Thanks for your reply. I think `c` is to separate the "speed###", "dist" and "speed" into `$col1`, `$col2` and `$rows`but it didn't  get the exactly the same output as `cols=list("speed###","dist"), rows=list("speed")`, am I missed some steps?

Comment: I am not following your structure.  Please use a dput to show what you intended, a list of lists or a single list with 3 elements?

Comment: You may not need a `list` at all. R lists are not like other programming languages you may have used.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the replies! I think I mess up R with different languages! :)

Answer (score 2):

What I think is happening with your code is:

1. You are passing `list("speed###","dist")` and `list("speed")` as parameters `cols` and `rows`, not as strings, and paste ignores names of parameters. Also, lists are converted to characters:`c("speed###","dist")`, `c("speed")`
2. Since parameters don't have the same length, the second is replicated (i.e. `c("speed###","dist")` and `c("speed", "speed")`).
3. Then, first elements are pasted together, and second elements are as well, returning a vector with each pasted string: `c("speed### speed", "dist speed")`

Why do you need what you are asking for? I mean, you plan to `do.call(matrix, list(cols=c("speed###","dist"), rows=c("speed")))` or something?

Besides, you should use `c` instead of list. I don't understand the need of using `list` here.

Comment: This brings up a valid point. OP may be mistakenly thinking that an R `list` is similar to Python lists, which are actually more like vectors.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it!